# QGIS3.8 Hotspot Analysis Plugin not installing

Tags: qgis, pysal

I'm hoping someone on here might be able to help me. I'm fairly new to working with QGIS I'm completely lost. For my PhD project I have to use QGIS to produce georeferenced heatmaps based on informants' hand-drawn maps. An academic from another institution has provided me with step-by-step instructions of what to install and the steps to follow, but I've hit a big problem with installing the Hotspot Analysis plugin in QGIS.

I am working on a Macbook. So far I have installed Python, as well as pip, numpy, scify, and pysal (as instructed). However, when I try to install the Hotspot Analysis plugin I keep getting this same error message:

> Couldn't load plugin 'HotspotAnalysis' due to an error when calling
>   its classFactory() method ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   'pysal.esda'

Does anyone have any idea how to rectify this? I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling everything. I've also tried installing the plugin from a zip file, but I still get the same message.

Comment: Hi, try also installing the edsa module: pip install esda

Comment: Thanks. I've just installed the esda module, but I'm still getting the same error message unfortunately.

Comment: @gariochquine - Have you read the [home GitHub page](https://github.com/danioxoli/HotSpotAnalysis_Plugin/tree/qgis3)? It's mentioned that the plugin hasn't been extensively tested yet for Macs but if you still have issues, you could consider posting a ticket.

Comment: Thanks. I've just raised an issue there. Hopefully someone gets back to me.